# Intuos BT S on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, wacom

[image]

I have this tablet and it is clearly connecting and recognizing. However, when I go to "Devices" -> "Wacom Tablet", nothing shows up on either "Stylus" or "Tablet" tabs.

[I believe this is the solution to my problem, but I'm not sure.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/merge_requests/324)

If it is, how do I update to that. If it isn't, what else should I try?

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? I seem to have the same issues and the answer hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your tablet is a CTL-4100WL, the [linuxwacom device IDs list](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs) says that your tablet requires version 0.30 of the libwacom database in order to be recognized by the GNOME Control Center. Ubuntu 18.04 only ships version 0.29, however, which would explain why nothing appears. Ubuntu 18.10 has an updated version of libwacom but will still be affected by the stylus bug you've linked to. If I recall correctly, the upcoming Ubuntu 19.04 release should have that bug fixed as well.

Note: the previously-mentioned page also notes that version 4.17 of the Linux kernel is required to use the tablet over Bluetooth (only version 4.10 to use it over USB) but Ubuntu 18.04 only ships version 4.15. I assume you've installed [the input-wacom driver](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source) to allow your device to work over Bluetooth.

Note 2: The GNOME Control Center currently has a known issue with button mapping on non-pro tablets. You may not be able to map all of the buttons and may notice that GNOME is confused about the physical location of the buttons that you *can* map.

Comment: Yes, it's a CTL-4100WL. I just bought it from Best Buy yesterday.
Awesome. I'm glad this is known bug and there is a solution (and I didn't just do it wrong). I'll update to 19.04 if I have to, but is there a way for me to get these particular fixes for my "otherwise working well" install?

Comment: @jigpu: Did you mean "... version ~~4.15~~ 4.17 of the Linux kernel is required to use the tablet over Bluetooth (only version 4.10 to use it over USB) but Ubuntu 18.04 only ships version 4.15"?  As of 2019-12-17, https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs specifies **4.17** under the **Linux** column for CTL-4100WL.

Comment: @HenrikB, indeed that looks like a typo on my part. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get it working. Providing the correct `.tablet` files and installing the driver from source:

#### 1. Copy the right `.tablet` files into `/usr/share/libwacom`

The `.tablet` files are available at: https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/tree/master/data

Search in the repository for your device ID (`VID:PID`):
https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs

`056a:0378      CTL-6100WL  Intuos BT M`

In my case I had to download two files for, as there is a second connection mode for android, which can make some [trouble](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect), too:

```
intuos-m-p3-wl.tablet
intuos-m-p3-wl-android.tablet
```

In a terminal do:

```bsh
cd /usr/share/libwacom
sudo mv ~/Downloads/intuos-m-p3-wl.tablet .
sudo chmod 644 intuos-m-p3-wl.tablet
sudo chown root:root intuos-m-p3-wl.tablet
```

#### 2. Install the driver from source

Download the `Source code (tar.gz)` like `input-wacom-input-wacom-0.46.0.tar.gz` (the one, which includes the `autogen.sh`) and follow the [instructions](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source):

2.1:

```
# Unpack
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvzf input-wacom-input-wacom-0.46.0.tar.gz
cd input-wacom-input-wacom-0.46.0
```

2.2:

```bsh
# Prepare Debian, Ubuntu, and Mint:
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)

# Install
if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
```

You may have also to update the [xorg driver](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver):

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom$(dpkg -S $(which Xorg) | grep -Eo -- "-hwe-[^:]*")"
```

Tada, in only two simple steps you have installed your pen tablet! /irony-off/

#### 3. Repeat step 2.2 after a kernel update